# Checking the definition of absolutely irreducible representations

Tags: representation-theory, definition

The definition of an irreducible representation $(\rho, V) $ is one with no subrepresentations.

Am I correct in saying that a absolutely irreducible means "it is irreducible over the algebraic closure of the ground field?"

Also implying  "absolutely irreducible $\implies$ irreducible" holds.

Thanks

Comment: Yes, that's correct. This is all on the Wikipedia article.

Comment: Are you talking about group representations? Lie Algebras? Give us some more information.